# сортировка python

Tags: python, сортировка

```
x = input()
def lcount():
    print('Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: ')
    for i in set(x):
        print(i, x.count(i), sep=' - ')
```

Как отсортировать те символы, которые будут выводится из слова которое принимает инпут, в алфавитном порядке?
т.е если ввести слово хорошо, то выдаст
Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: 
о - 3
х - 1
р - 1
ш - 1

Как сделать что бы буквы выводились в алфавитном порядке ?

Comment: вместо `set(x)` напишите `sorted(set(x))`

Comment: @MrMorgan Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос: вместо `set(x)` напишите `sorted(set(x))`, а именно:

```
x = input()
def lcount():
    print('Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: ')
    for i in sorted(set(x)):
        print(i, x.count(i), sep=' - ')
```

Однако я бы хотел порекомендовать Вам использовать такую вещь, как аргументы функции - это полезно для улучшения читаемости и поддержки кода:

```py
user_data = input()
def lcount(x):
    print('Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: ')
    for i in sorted(set(x)):
        print(i, x.count(i), sep=' - ')
lcount(user_data)
```

Также хочу заметить, что данный код - неэффективен, а именно [асимптотика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5) этого кода в худшем случае равна `O(n^2)`,  потому как мы пробегаемся по списку и каждый раз, вызывая метод `.count` мы пробегаемся по нему ещё раз. Можете обратиться к `Counter` из модуля [collections](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-collections.html), который имеет асимптотику `O(n)`

Также предлагаю Вам не выводить результат сразу на экран, а делать это в другой функции - это позволит делегировать "обязанности" функций

Итак, финальный код без использования `Counter` может выглядеть так:

```py
user_data = input()
def lcount(x):
    res = []
    for i in sorted(set(x)):
        res.append((i, x.count(i)))
    return res

def print_answer(x):
    print('Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: ')
    for i, count in x:
        print(i, count, sep=' - ')
answer = lcount(user_data)
print_answer(answer)
```

С использованием:

```py
from collections import Counter
user_data = input()
def lcount(x):
    c = Counter(x)
    return c

def print_answer(x):
    print('Сколько раз встречается каждый знак: ')
    for i, count in sorted(x.items()): # <<<<<<<<<<< тут код немного поменялся. обращаю внимание
        print(i, count, sep=' - ')
answer = lcount(user_data)
print_answer(answer)
```